# What are the output shape of LSTM with "return_sequences" equal to "True" or "False"?

Tags: lstm

What are the output shape of LSTM with `Keras` implementation when "return_sequences" equals to "True" or "False" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your output state size is `h`. You will generate `nxh` for `n` data points if `return_sequences` is `false`. On the other hand you would be having `nxtxh` dimensional array as output if `return_sequences` is set to `true`. Here `t` is the number of timestamps in each data point.

Comment: So choosing `return_sequences` = `True/False` doesn't change the 3D array output shape?

Comment: It does. In false case you got last hidden state out. But in true case every internal hidden state gets released out.

Comment: Aha, you meant one dimension vector by `h`.

Comment: Yes. That is right.